# Can one have almost everywhere convergence in the Sobolev approximation theorems?

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, sobolev-spaces

Here are two theorems regarding the Sobolev functions from Evans's Partial Differential Equations:

[image]
[image]

Here is my question:

Is there any handy theorem showing that the modes of convergence in the above theorems can also be "almost everywhere" convergence?

Comment: Every $L^p$ convergent sequence has an almost everywhere convergent subsequence.

Comment: To add to @MaoWao when $k > n/p$, $W^{k,p}(U)$ is embedded into $C^{0,\alpha}(\bar{U})$, so the sequence converges uniformly as well (and so it converges everywhere).

Comment: @Jeff: Yes, thanks to Morrey's inequality.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to MaoWao's comment, one should consider the following theorem:

> Every $L^p$ convergent sequence has an almost everywhere convergent subsequence.